# excel vlookup 2 workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

Am trying to programme a lookup across 2 workbook with workbook path and name linked to cell for dynamic updates ... my current code is getting an error:

"object does not support property or method" on line 29 set lookfor

Can you help me resolve this?

```
Sub Lookup()

Dim wb1 As String, wb2 As String
Dim wbook1 As Workbook, wbook2 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lookFor As Range
Dim srchRange As Range
Dim wb1name As String, wb2name As String
Dim wb1path As String, wb2path As String
Dim sFormulaPre As String, sFormulaSuff As String
Dim rowstart As Long


wb1name = Workbooks("r.xlsm").Sheets("Front sheet").Range("B3").Text
wb2name = Workbooks("r.xlsm").Sheets("Front sheet").Range("AA1").Text

wb1path = Workbooks("r.xlsm").Sheets("Front sheet").Range("AB1").Text
wb2path = Workbooks("r.xlsm").Sheets("Front sheet").Range("AB1").Text

wb1 = wb1path & wb1name
wb2 = wb2path & wb1name

Set wbook1 = Workbooks(wb1name)
Set wbook2 = Workbooks(wb2name)

Set ws1 = wbook1.Sheets("DATA1")
Set ws2 = wbook2.Sheets("DATA")

Set lookFor = wbook2.ws2.Range("$G:$J")
Set srchRange = wbook1.ws1.Range("$A:$E")

Dim bIsEmpty As Boolean

sFormulaPre = "vlookup(D"
sFormulaSuff = ",srchRange, 2,FALSE)"

If IsEmpty(Workbooks("r.xlsm").Sheets("Front sheet").Range("Y1")) = False Then
    With wbook2.ws2
       rowstart = .Cells(G, 11)
       MsgBox sFormulaPre & rowstart & sFormulaSuff
    End With
ElseIf IsEmpty(Workbooks("Rates, percentages calculator.xlsm").Sheets("Front sheet").Range("Y1")) = True Then
    bIsEmpty = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `rowstart = .Cells(G, 11)`.  Is that meant to be `rowstart = .Cells(11, "G")` perhaps?

Comment: That doesn't work

Comment: What are you trying to do with `rowstart = .Cells(G, 11)`?  That is assigning the variable `rowstart` to have the value of the cell in column K in the row defined by the variable `G` (and `G` doesn't seem to have been given a value, so would be `0`, so you are accessing the non-existent cell `K0`).  Is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already Set your `ws2` worksheet object to `wbook2`, with this line `Set ws2 = wbook2.Sheets("DATA")`

so change your :

```
Set lookFor = wbook2.ws2.Range("$G:$J")
```

to:

```
Set lookFor = ws2.Range("$G:$J")
```

---

The same goes for:

```
Set srchRange = wbook1.ws1.Range("$A:$E")
```

should be:

```
Set srchRange = ws1.Range("$A:$E")
```

**And**, change `With wbook2.ws2`

to: `With ws2`

Comment: That is running now but something not working with the "rowstart" - I want the vlookup to run the whole D column

Comment: @tj123 if you explain what your code is trying to achieve, perhaps I can offer a more relaible (and easier) solution

Comment: I want the vlookup to complete colums G to J for rows 11-293 in ws2